# Storm Topology not Executing in Cluster

Tags: java, apache-storm, topology

submit my topo via `stormsubmitter.submittopoloy`. can see the topo in the storm UI, but the emitted number is always 0.

```
    TopologyBuilder builder = new TopologyBuilder();
    builder.setSpout("WordSpout", new WordSpout());
    builder.setBolt("WordSplitBolt", new WordSplitBolt(),5).shuffleGrouping("WordSpout");
    builder.setBolt("WordCountBolt", new WordCountBolt(),5).fieldsGrouping("WordSplitBolt", new Fields("word"));
    builder.setBolt("WordReportBolt", new WordReportBolt(),10).globalGrouping("WordCountBolt");



    Config cfg = new Config();
    cfg.setDebug(true);



    try{
        StormSubmitter.submitTopology("wordcount-topo", cfg, builder.createTopology());
    }
    catch (AlreadyAliveException e)
    {

    }
    catch (InvalidTopologyException e)
    {

    }
    catch (AuthorizationException e)
    {

    }
```

See the screenshot here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/w7JrG.jpg

Recieved the following error in the `work.log` file:

```
2019-10-16 11:51:08.973 STDERR Thread-0 [INFO] Unrecognized VM option 'PrintGCDateStamps'
2019-10-16 11:51:08.973 STDERR Thread-1 [INFO] [0.000s][warning][gc] -Xloggc is deprecated. Will use -Xlog:gc:artifacts/gc.log instead.
2019-10-16 11:51:08.977 STDERR Thread-0 [INFO] Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine.
2019-10-16 11:51:08.978 STDERR Thread-0 [INFO] Error: A fatal exception has occurred. Program will exit.
```

Answer (score 0):

fixed, should be the java version difference.

target storm cluster java version is 11. my dev environment java version for developing the topo is 8, that caused the problem.

adjust the java version to make them the same fix the problem

Answer (score 0):

That problem still exists in the official docker images for 2.3.0. Got the supervisors working with overriding the worker.childopts:

```
docker run -d --restart always --name storm-supervisor --link storm-zk:zookeeper --link storm-nimbus:nimbus storm storm supervisor -c worker.childopts=-Xmx2048m
```